# Why does the cape choose Dr. Stephen Strange?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

I've seen Doctor Strange but I didn't understand why the cape chooses Stephen.

I know that the cape is his Relic. Please answer in detail.

Comment: _"Please answer in detail"_ - aye, sir! Also, there's a related question of SFF: [Why does the Cloak of Levitation “accept” Doctor Strange so quickly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143834/why-does-the-cloak-of-levitation-accept-doctor-strange-so-quickly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to be let down, because there is no "in detail" answer to this.  The cloak, of it's own will, simply deems Dr. Strange "worthy".  For an unknown reason, which is never explained, the cloak chooses him.  And that's it.

Answer (score 8):

### It simply liked him

There is not much detail to point it out here, according to the *[Cloak of Levitation Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Levitation)*, the cloak simply chooses Dr.Strange.

> Many relics choose their owners, and this was the case with Dr. Stephen Strange when he was deeply entrenched in battle with the rogue sorcerer Kaecilius in the New York Sanctum.

**It's not like Thor's hammer**

Thor's hammer can be picked by anyone who is **worthy** at anytime (Vision already showed us that in Age of Ultron). The cloak already **chose** Strange so it can't be worn by anyone else.

Comment: Its same like Thor then, the one who is worthy shall posses the weapon :) is it mentioned anywhere of the origin of this cloak.

Comment: @anvesh.veerelli So little is known about the cloak before it was given to Dr.Strange, you can find some details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_of_Levitation

Comment: @anvesh.veerelli I wouldn't compare it to Thor's hammer, Mjolnir. Being worthy is a quantifiable measure. When Thor is not worthy, he can't pick the hammer. When others are, they can. The cloak just chose Strange. There is no lore of a relic chosing different owners, unlike Thor's hammer.

Comment: Is there a reason he gets the cape in the comics?